# Error while trying to decode a JSON object

Tags: c#

I am trying to decode a JSON object 'BuildTestPlans' to find out distinct `BuildID` and save all records(for example,BuildID `0` there are 2 records) corresponding to it but running into below error,how to fix it?

```
BuildTestPlans:
[
  {
    "BuildTestPlanID": 0,
    "BuildID": 0,
    "Build": "string",
    "TestPlanMasterID": 0

  },
 {
    "BuildTestPlanID": 0,
    "BuildID": 0,
    "Build": "string1",
    "TestPlanMasterID": 0
  },
 {
    "BuildTestPlanID": 1,
    "BuildID": 1,
    "Build": "string",
    "TestPlanMasterID": 0
 }
]
```

```
public List<BuildTestPlan> AddOrUpdate(List<BuildTestPlan> BuildTestPlans)
{
    foreach (var BuildID in BuildTestPlans.BuildID.Distinct())
    {
        //save all records for each buildID
    }
    return null;
}
```

Error:

> List does not contain a definition for BuildID and no extension method 'BuildID' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This hasn't got anything to do with your json. You're trying to access `BuildID` on a *list* of `BuildTestPlan`. Your code should be `foreach (var buildId in BuildTestPlans.Select(btp => btp.BuildID).Distinct())`

Comment: @Rob - thanks a lot,how to save all the corresponding records for each buildID,for example,BuildID 0 there are 2 records

Comment: You'd loop through the list like you would any list. `foreach(var build in BuildTestPlans) { }`

Comment: I guess you're working on the list `BuildTestPlans` but not `BuildTestPlans.BuildID`.

Comment: ydoww - you are right,but I need to save the corresponding records for each BuilID,I need to be able to figure out the records,something like a dictionary with build ID as key and the corresponding records as values

Comment: @Rob - I am confused,would I need two for loops,would a dictinoary help here?

Comment: @user3508811 No, you would only need the second loop I showed. Then, each 'Id' would be accessed via `build.BuildID` inside the loop. Each `build` would be an object in the array. You don't need a dictionary here if you're just iterating the items.

Comment: @Rob - Would you provide a sample on what exactly you meant,really appreciate,its not clear to me how would I have the list of all the records given a Build ID

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `BuildTestPlan.BuildID` is `int`

```
// processed list, initially empty
List<int> buildList = new List<int>();

foreach (var buildTestPlan in BuildTestPlans)
{

    // if the BuildID was not previously processed
    if (buildList.IndexOf(buildTestPlan.BuildID) < 0){
        buildList.Add(buildTestPlan.BuildID);
        // todo: process the buildTestPlan for this newly found BuildID
    } 

    // if the BuildID was previously processed
    else {
        // todo: something else, or skip it
    }   
}
return null;
```

Added here regarding your comment -

> create a list of all the buildTestPlan for a BuildID

Assuming you want to extract `buildTestPlan` for `BuildID = 0`, it's probably the list you are expecting.

```
var BuildTestPlans_WithParticularBuildId = BuildTestPlans.Select(c => c.BuildID == 0);
```

Comment: ydoww - can you explain what `buildList.IndexOf(buildTestPlan.BuildID` is doing?index of specifically

Comment: @user3508811, it's a list storing processed `BuildID`, the particular code is checking whether the `BuildID` has been previously processed. I created this logical branch because there's a `Distinct` in your code. You may want to process differently for new / existing `BuildID`

Comment: I actually want to create a list of all the `buildTestPlan` for a BuildID,above just creates a list of BuildID's

Comment: also,this throws an  error `buildList is a variable but used like a type`

Comment: My bad, try again `List<int> buildList = new List<int>();`

Comment: ydoow - Thanks a lot for your help....one last problem `var BuildTestPlans_WithParticularBuildId = BuildTestPlans.Select(c => c.BuildID == 0);` is not working as expected,does it work for you,I dont see the buildtestplan info

Comment: What error message did you get? To access the data in the list, you have to do `foreach (var buildTestPlan in BuildTestPlans_WithParticularBuildId) { }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131005/discussion-between-user3508811-and-ydoow).

Answer (score 1):

List of BuildTestPlans clearly doesnt have `BuildID` since it is a List of BuildTestPlans and not the object you can access it but the index number like `buildtestplans[0]` here is the way you can access it

```
    public List<BuildTest> AddOrUpdate(List<BuildTest> BuildTestPlans)
    {
        List<int> BTPBuildID = new List<int>();
        foreach(var BuildTP in BuildTestPlans)
        {
             BTPBuildID.Add(BuildTP.BuildID);
        }
        BTPBuildID.Distinct();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

There's a missing brace on your json before the closing bracket this should work